# product of integrals with common factor

Tags: calculus, integration, probability-distributions, products

Is there any useful way to combine this product of two integrals into a single integral?

$$\int f(x)g(x)dx \int f(x)h(x)dx$$

What if $f(x)$ is a distribution such that $\int f(x)dx = 1$?

Comment: What you're looking for is the convolution. The product of two integrals is the integral of the convolution of the integrands.

Comment: Thanks!  So, then this equals $\int fg\ast fh dx$ where $\ast$ is the convolution operator.  Any way to factor out $f$?